# error in login form wrote using java swing (with database file)

Tags: java, swing, authentication

I've got an error while validating username and password in this Java Swing code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

public class LoginForm extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JButton login;
    private JTextField name;
    private JPasswordField pw;

    private LoginForm() {
        super("Log in");
        login = new JButton("Log in");
        name = new JTextField(20);
        pw = new JPasswordField(20);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel fields = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        fields.add(name, "North");
        fields.add(new JScrollPane(), "Center");
        fields.add(pw, "South");
        add(fields, "Center");
        add(new JPanel(), "South");
        add(new JPanel(), "North");
        JPanel j = new JPanel();
        j.setSize(100, 400);
        j.add(login);
        //j.add(new JLabel("|\n|\n|-> Username"));
        setSize(600, 400);
        add(j, "West");
        login.addActionListener(this);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LoginForm();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getSource() == login) {
            if (!validUser(name.getText(), pw.getPassword())) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This user not exists.\nFor create a user,\n  edit 'database.lfrm' file."
                , "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This user is valid! Congraulations!");
        } else throw new RuntimeException("Event source isn't be a " + login.toString());
    }
    private static boolean validUser(String name, char[] pwd) {
        boolean res = false;
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("database.lfrm"));
            String all = "", lines[], user[], line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) all += line;
            lines = all.split("\n");
            user = Arrays.asList(lines).get(Arrays.asList(lines).indexOf(name + " $ " + new String(pwd))).split(" $ ");
            if (user == new String[]{name, new String(pwd)}) res = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        return res;
    }
}
```

I compiled and run this code, and I had this "error":
"
This user not exists.
For create a user, edit 'database.lfrm' file.
"
My 'database.lfrm' file is likes this:
"
JavaUser $ adimn
"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is here:

```
if (user == new String[]{name, new String(pwd)}) res = true;
```

When you do this, you are checking if "user" and the String[] element are the same object, which is not true, because the String[] element is a different object you are creating just for this validation.

What you want to check is if the contents of the "user" array and the next array are the same, which you can solve replacing this line by:

```
if (Arrays.equals(user, new String[] {name, new String(pwd)})) res = true;
```